# JavaFX, how to shuffle all nodes in GridPane?

Tags: java, javafx, shuffle

I am making match cards game. I am struggling with shuffling all `buttons` in `grid pane`. I have 16 `buttons` in `grid pane`. It is like board of `4x4`. What i want is at one point to shuffle all `buttons`.

Is there any method to do it ? Or I need to do it with random generator?

Comment: I doubt that a functionality to "shuffle" your controls exists. I would use a random generator.